# How can I run sshpass command with the remote environment, taking the source ~/.bashrc effect

Tags: bash, sshpass

For example, I run a command:

```
sshpass -p passwd ssh dennis@ip python xx.py
```

But, in this way, this command is running without the environment variables, which is set in `/home/dennis/.bashrc`. e.g.: `export PYTHON_HOME=/python`

is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution, though not necessarily the best:

```
sshpass -p passwd ssh dennis@ip "(./.bashrc;python xx.py)"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a try